# Ping Code to reply another color

Tags: powershell, ping

I am very new to coding so I know very little.

I am writing my first code which is a ping. It can ping any workstation ID that you put in it. I would like that when it pings, the reply would be green and request timed out would be red.

I just want to test it out and learn from it. So far I have this:

```
$Search = Read-Host "Enter Workstation ID"
$Reply = ping -t $Search

if ($Reply -like "Request Timed Out.") {
    Write-Host $Reply -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

But that is not working.

Comment: What isn't working about it? Are there errors? If so, what are they? Is it giving the wrong result? No Result? Right result wrong color?

Comment: You *could* use a native PowerShell cmdlet instead of `ping` ( > `Test-Connection`), that will save you *some* trouble (string parsing).

Comment: It's not giving me an error it just doing nothing

Comment: @NickLevesque oh it is, it just never stops

Comment: Lol I hadn't seen the `-t` switch ... @Nick you're `ping`ing forever and PS is waiting for the output of the command. This is where *trouble* begins.

Comment: `-t` means ping forever until cancelled.

Comment: I would be glad to see what would be proposed as an equivalent to `ping -t` in pure PowerShell, though. This has always boggled me.

Comment: @sodawillow Is `Test-Connection -Count ([int]::MaxValue)` close enough? :)

Comment: I have used that in the past. I generally still prefer ping -t if I am watching for drops because I can periodically use CTRL-PAUSE to see the stats without stopping or resetting the accumulated stats.

Comment: Oh okay I get what you guys mean, thanks I'll give it a shot!

Comment: But yes my main purpose was to use it with -t to verify if there are any dropped packets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the usage message from `ping.exe`, you'll see that the `-t` switch makes `ping.exe` continue pinging the host until interrupted by Ctrl+C or Ctrl+Break.

That's why it seems like it's "doing nothing".

I would probably go for the `Test-Connection` cmdlet, rather than `ping.exe`:

```
$Hostname = Read-Host "please enter the hostname..."
if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $Hostname -Quiet)
{
    Write-Host "Ping succeeded!" -ForegroundColor Green
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Ping failed!" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

It doesn't have a `-t` parameter, but you can provide a ridiculously high value to the `-Count` parameter, and make due with that (with a second in between each request, `[int]::MaxValue` gives you 2^31 seconds, or 68 years worth of pinging):

```
Test-Connection $Hostname -Count ([int]::MaxValue)
```

---

If you sincerely want the `-t` switch, you can't rely on assignment to a variable, since PowerShell will wait for `ping.exe` to return (which, intentionally, never happens).

You *can* however pipe the standard output from `ping.exe`, and PowerShell's asynchronous runtime will keep them coming for as long as you like:

```
function Keep-Pinging
{
    param([string]$Hostname)

    ping.exe -t $Hostname |ForEach-Object {
        $Color = if($_ -like "Request timed out*") {
            "Red"
        } elseif($_ -like "Reply from*") {
            "Green"
        } else {
            "Gray"
        }
        Write-Host $_ -ForegroundColor $Color
    }
}
```

[image: ping away!]

Comment: I have experienced failure with `-Count` less than `2`, a computer would only answer from the second packet received or whatnot.

Comment: Yeah I would definitely need the -t because I will be using this to observe dropped packets if ever the user has trouble with the network or the field server itself is dropping packets.

Comment: @NickLevesque Ahh, I see, there's a solution for that as well! :)

Comment: I <3 `ping -t` and so now I will <3 `Keep-Pinging` :-). Depending on your OS, you might want to use `ping.exe -4 -t $Hostname` to get IPv4 instead of IPv6